# Exact date & time in subprogram with powershell

Tags: date, powershell, batch-file

I'm new to powershell and I try to solve a problem I already managed to solve with batch scripting. I know how to set a variable and how to get the date with powershell. But I made a special subprogram for the exact date and time in batch and I don't know how to do that in powershell. Also I'm asking myself if there's an equivalent for %~dpn0 in powershell?

This are the parts of my batch script I want to use in powershell:

```
set pgm=%~n0
set log=%~dpn0.log
set csv=%~dpn0.csv
set dir=%~dp0users
set txt=%~n0.txt
set fix=%~dpn0.fix

call :loggy I "Program %pgm% started..."

:loggy
set welcomesev=%1
set welcometxt=%~2

set welcomeJJJJ=%date:~6,4%
set welcomeMM=%date:~3,2%
set welcomeDD=%date:~0,2%
set welcomeHR=%time:~0,2%
set welcomeMIN=%time:~3,2%
set welcomeSEC=%time:~6,2%
set welcomeDT=%welcomeJJJJ%.%welcomeMM%.%welcomeDD% %welcomeHR%:%welcomeMIN%:%welcomeSEC%

echo %welcomeDT%   [%welcomesev%]     %welcometxt% 1>>%log%
goto :EOF
```

Sorry for the many questions but I couldn't find anything with the search function.

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this function help you?

```
function Extract-CurrentDate{

    $date = (Get-Date -Format d).ToString() 
    $time = (Get-Date -Format t).ToString()

    Write-Host "$date $time"
} 

Extract-CurrentDate
```

In generell you can use the Cmdlet `Get-Date` for you issue. It has many options, see [this article.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx) Moreover, you can [format your output](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx) like this.

Comment: Thanks that worked just fine! Do you also know what the powershell version of `%~dpn0` is?

Comment: If you want so know the PS-Version, type `$PSVersionTable`